# Restart wifi using bash script and systemd service?

Tags: networking, wifi, raspbian-jessie, systemd-unit

My rpi is connected to a captive portal hotspot. I have prepared a python login script to login to the captive portal and it was working fine. But sometimes the wifi is getting disconnected and at that time i need to restart the wifi. Hence I have prepared a systemd service called restartwifi.service and it is given as follows. When I need to restart the service, I will start the service. But it won't help me.

```
[Unit]
Description=captive portal automation

[Service]
Type=simple

ExecStart=/home/pi/.caportal/do.sh
```

The script do.sh is given as

```
#!/bin/bash

ifdown wlan0 
ifup wlan0
```

When i start the service, ifdown and ifup are working fine but after the complete execution, if I run ifconfig, it will give the following output.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:57:b8:d9  
          inet addr:192.168.42.1  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d490:e6a8:b4dc:4c65/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10856 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10767 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:976358 (953.4 KiB)  TX bytes:3940237 (3.7 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e342:200d:c1ad:eda1/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:690 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:690 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:63416 (61.9 KiB)  TX bytes:63416 (61.9 KiB)
```

and the systemctl status restartwifi is look like below.

```
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/restartwifi.service; static)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Aug 27 15:45:38 raspberrypi dhclient[8349]: DHCPREQUEST on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Aug 27 15:45:38 raspberrypi dhclient[8349]: DHCPOFFER from 192.168.1.1
Aug 27 15:45:38 raspberrypi do.sh[7957]: DHCPREQUEST on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Aug 27 15:45:38 raspberrypi do.sh[7957]: DHCPOFFER from 192.168.1.1
Aug 27 15:45:38 raspberrypi dhclient[8349]: DHCPACK from 192.168.1.1
Aug 27 15:45:38 raspberrypi do.sh[7957]: DHCPACK from 192.168.1.1
Aug 27 15:45:38 raspberrypi dhclient[8349]: bound to 192.168.1.4 -- renewal in 36059 seconds.
Aug 27 15:45:38 raspberrypi do.sh[7957]: bound to 192.168.1.4 -- renewal in 36059 seconds.
Aug 27 15:45:38 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[8345]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=58:d7:59:38:58:f4 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Aug 27 15:45:39 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[8345]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
```

But all working fine if I run the script `do.sh` alone in the terminal. What happen when I run the script in systemd service?

Comment: Your service does not have any dependency when it should run. So it starts on boot up as one of the first services ever. It will not find any initialized networking. Then it finishes after a short time (after doing ifdown/ifup). You should use `Type=oneshot` instead of default `Type=simple`. Why running the script just one time on early boot up? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Ingo I am not running the service at boot. I only start the service when i need to restart the wifi.

Comment: @Milliways Why you are always doing a negative approach. Sometimes, wifi is not connecting or sometimes we need to modify the configuration and need to restart the wifi.

Comment: @Ingo I have tried by `Type=oneshot` but nothing changed.. I got same result. Wifi is getting disconnected on service termination.

Comment: You don't enable the service? You shouldn't cripple the output of commands. Why do yo need a service then? Just execute `/home/pi/.caportal/do.sh` and it is done.

Comment: This was a test script. Actually, I need to run this script inside another script which is running in systemd service.

Comment: I haven't enabled the service. I just start the service when i need. Why the systemd service stop the wifi when it terminate?

Comment: First, I haven't used old-old stable *Jessie* since years, so I cannot help much with deprecated **ifupdown**. You may consider to use the up to date version *Buster*. But with the systemd Unit it would be better you give the general context for what you want to achieve with the other script and we can see its dependencies. Maybe it isn't needed to use a separate service.

Comment: If I use latest OS, is there any way to recover this?

Comment: After configuring the wpa_supplicant.conf we need to restart the service, right?

Comment: My question is specific that Why we cant do wifi restart using systemd service?

Comment: @Milliways You are asking questions above my question. The issue was simple that wifi restart is not working on systemd service

Comment: @mcv, Try to understand how the system work. The system start/boot and all daemons are started (async). In this daemons you can find (for network specific) : network.service, networking.service, etc... use `sudo systemctl list-unit-files` and find all related to network, check the contents of these files to understand what is happening. These services start wpa_cli (Wi-Fi auth/connect), call the dhcp client (get an IP addr), configure the interfaces (mount interface) etc... If you want a working service, you must disable all the default start-up services that can pose a conflict problem.

Comment: Nop. I got the solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Modified the `.service` file as follows

```
[Unit]
Description=captive portal automation

[Service]
Type=simple
KillMode=process

ExecStart=/home/pi/.caportal/do.sh
```

That's it!

Thanks for the comments

Comment: I do not understand what you are doing. What is the child process? A two liner bash script that also terminates after a second?

Comment: Yup that's confusion. But the problem is solved now. From the status in my question `wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=58:d7:59:38:58:f4 reason=3 locally_generated=1`, we can understand the wifi is get disconnected when the service terminates. But after giving `KillMode`, its not like that and the wifi is still connected.